# jQuery - Edit in place - with hidden fields and no POST

Tags: jquery, edit-in-place

Many solutions I've found involve live POSTing the data that was changed. I don't want that.

I am looking to:

- transform a div / span (on click / focus) into an input (like any normal Edit it place does)
- hide the input but keep it in the DOM so that I can make an Ajax request where I can **serialize all the inputs** in the form.

Comment: why don't you try something like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/UnK9f/1/

Comment: +1 There is a good point in your idea there. I just need to find a decent way of removing any CSS applied to the elements.